# question_id missing from migration_info for this question.

Tags: bug, status-completed, filter

Consider the following API request:

> http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions/3064?site=stackapps

This question was migrated from [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/3064) to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9121192). However, the `migrated_to` field is missing `question_id`. According to the [documentation for `migration_info`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/migration-info), `question_id` should be contained in the response when using the default filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this has been deployed.

We were fetching the new question id, but then immediately discarding it.  Actually returning the data now.